# How do I delete a row based on duplicate value in the column in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with value like this

```
ID     quality  a       b       c       d       e       f       g
687     94.69   10      8       10      9       9       10      9
691     100 10  10      10      10      10      10      10     10
180     70.49   10      7       6       9       7       7       7
```

I would like to delete the ID 691 because they have duplicate value among column a to g

```
ID      quality  a      b       c       d       e       f       g
687     94.69   10      8       10      9       9       10      9
180     70.49   10      7       6       9       7       7       7
```

I have tried using  inner join but it does not return the result i want.

```sql
DELETE R1 FROM survey R1
JOIN survey R2
ON R1.a = R2.a
AND R1.b = R2.b
AND R1.c = R2.c
AND R1.d = R2.d
AND R1.e = R2.e
AND R1.f = R2.f
AND R1.g = R2.g
AND R2.id < R1.id;
```

Comment: Please show your workings as they say in all good exam rooms

Comment: Do all the columns a to g have to be the same number for the delete to happen?

Comment: yes, the column have to be same throughout a to g and the whole row needs to be deleted.

Comment: Your query looks good. When you run it, what happens that you don't like?

Comment: Hi so sorry about it, turns out i input one wrong value. Its all good now! thanks

Comment: What's wrong with `delete from survey where a = b and b = c and c = d and d = e and e = f and f = g`?